# Maven project in Netbeans: How to add dependency to both 'Dependencies' and 'Test Dependencies'?

Tags: maven, scope, dependencies, netbeans-7.1

I have a Maven project in Netbeans 7.1 IDE.

I'd like to add the same dependency to both `Dependencies` and `Test Dependencies`.

Adding to one removes it from the other.

Duplicating the dependency in pom.xml and including in one of them:

```
<scope>test</scope>
```

..doesn't work either.

Help!

**More Details:**

Assume I have projects `MyProject` and `MyDependency`.

`MyProject` contains `MyDependency` as a default scope (i.e. `compile` scope) dependency:

```
<dependencies>
          <dependency>
                    <groupId>my.group.id</groupId>
                    <artifactId>AnArtifactId</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
          </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

`MyProject` contains several classes in the `Source Packages` folder (i.e. `MyProject/src/main/...`) which reference classes within `MyDependency` **source** packages. These work perfectly; Netbeans shows no red error flags and those classes compile successfully.

`MyProject` contains several classes in the `Test Packages` folder (i.e. `MyProject/src/test/...`) which reference classes within `MyDependency` **test** packages. Netbeans displays red error flags in `MyProject` for these references.

`MyDependency` has been cleaned, built and stored in local Maven repo using `mvn clean install -DskipTests`. Running the same command for `MyProject` causes errors within the test classes only; the non-test classes compile fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I discovered the solution is to duplicate the pom dependency entry as follows:

```
<dependencies>
          <dependency>
                    <groupId>my.group.id</groupId>
                    <artifactId>AnArtifactId</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
                    <groupId>my.group.id</groupId>
                    <artifactId>AnArtifactId</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                    <type>test-jar</type>
          </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Specifying solely `<scope>test</scope>` would indicate that the jar containing source packages of `MyDependency` should be used as a dependency for the test packages of `MyProject`.

However, by specifying `<type>test-jar</type>` the test jar (i.e. jar containing test packages) for `MyDependency` is used as a dependency for the test packages of `MyProject`.

Answer (score 0):

`Dependencies` are automatically `Test Dependencies` as well, but not the other way around.

Comment: Thanks, I thought as much. So why is it that my classes in `Source Packages` recognise the dependency yet those in `Test Packages` cannot? It's not just a Netbeans glitch, attempting to build with `mvn` in bash doesn't work for the test classes :( Could it be because I've put the references used by the tests into 'Test Packages' within my dependency? i.e. can a project's test package see a dependency's test package when the dependency is the default <scope>compile</scope> ?

Comment: I can't due to company policy. However I've added to my OP as much additional info as I feel will be useful. Any further advice would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Kudos for respecting company policy. Unfortunately it's still important to see POM file. You could try to minimize and obfuscate it.

Comment: The only reference from one project to another is in the location I've exemplified within 'More Details' in my OP, i.e. within a single `<dependency>` tag which itself is within a `<project>` level `<dependencies>` tag. No more of the pom should be needed, but thank you anyway.